# Maps in Print Composers disappearing

Tags: qgis, print-composer

Does anyone know if this is a bug? It's been happening to me very often lately. I finish I map and export it and it's all good. Save the map and then when I open it again a few days later to make a change or whatever the print composer is empty as if I had never produced the map.

Comment: That definitely sounds like a bug. Please make a bug report. https://issues.qgis.org/projects/qgis/issues/

Comment: Are you locking the style in the print composer?

Comment: I'll report it as a bug. Thanks. And yes, I'm locking the the style.It happens randomly. I can't figure it what is making saved composers just disappear.

Comment: As per the [help/on-topic] it is OK to try and reproduce software problems in a Q&A here, but if you think this is a bug then be sure to submit it to the QGIS development team. Please post a link to the bug report here.